# MSSQL connection establishment in PHP 5.6

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to run PHP  application on my PC with MSSQL and this is the first time I am doing.
I have already configured XAMPP on my PC and started Apache but It's showing ODBC 11 driver installation problem and when I'm trying to install ODBC 11 it's showing operating system problem.

Comment: Are you using http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php? If so see `This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.`, use PDO, or the alternatives listed on that page.

Comment: I've using PHP 5.6 and installed these drivers
 (php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll 
php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll) in C:\xampp\php\ext folder and configured them in php.ini (extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll 
extension =php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll) 
and when my cheking sqlsrvc in php info it's running.

My query for connectivity is 
$serverName = "FIROZ\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName
   $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"e-vivah");
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

Comment: and here is my code for fetching data 
if( $conn === false ) 
{
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.vendor WHERE city =$city";
   $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
   if( $stmt === false)
   {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
   }
   while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
   {
    echo $row['name'].", ".$row['address'].$row['city'].", " .$row['number']."," .$row['type'];
   }
   sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

Comment: after your `$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo); ` to do this and check it. here we go `if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}`